# .net http Request using proxy 404 error not found

Tags: .net, http, proxy

I am using .net desktop app to make http requests to my site using proxy.
When i make the request using proxy it works fine for http://www.mySite.com, but it returns 404 error when i try to do a request on for example http://www.mySite.com/someSection

When i make the request without proxy it works fine for both cases.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(websiteURL);
                WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(@"http://payforexsurf.info", false);
                request.Proxy = proxy;
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just looked at their website and I can not see where they are advertising it as a proxy service that can be used in this manner.  Your code does look correct and should work against a proper proxy service.  I think the problem is that this web based "Webpage Requesting" service is not a proper proxy server.

Hope that this helps